# Select n rows containing at least one of a columns possible values

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this Table:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | title    | language |
+----+----------+----------+
| 10 | Title 1  | de       |
| 11 | Title 2  | de       |
| 12 | Title 3  | de       |
| 13 | Title 4  | fr       |
| 14 | Title 5  | fr       |
| 15 | Title 6  | fr       |
| 16 | Title 7  | fr       |
| 17 | Title 8  | it       |
| 18 | Title 9  | it       |
| 19 | Title 10 | it       |
| 20 | Title 11 | en       |
| 21 | Title 12 | en       |
| 22 | Title 13 | en       |
+----+----------+----------+
```

I would like to retrieve (n) rows containing **at least** one of each defined language.

Currently the language column is a ENUM Datatype with 4 predefined language values. If this would have to be changed to something more efficient, i'm open to suggestions.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks already for all the help.

Comment: Can you post a concrete example of what such a select would return? Is `n` a parameter?

Comment: The SELECT would return (for example) 5 rows containing at least 1 row of each possible language.

Answer (score 0):

select * from table where langauge in ('de','fr','it','en') --use limit N  to get set of N rows

Comment: This will not guarantee that there is at least one of every language.